# ng github-pages:deploy error

Tags: git, angular, github-pages, angular-cli

I've been trying to deploy a sample app on github pages but it always gives me an error everytime I run `ng github-pages:deploy`. Here's the error I'm getting:

Command failed: git rm -r
usage: git rm [] [--] ...

```
-n, --dry-run         dry run
-q, --quiet           do not list removed files
--cached              only remove from the index
-f, --force           override the up-to-date check
-r                    allow recursive removal
--ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched
```

Error: Command failed: git rm -r
usage: git rm [] [--] ...

```
-n, --dry-run         dry run
-q, --quiet           do not list removed files
--cached              only remove from the index
-f, --force           override the up-to-date check
-r                    allow recursive removal
--ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched


at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors, github pages deploy has been removed from ng-cli and will be available as different npm [refactor(@angular/cli): removed the github pages deploy command #4385](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4385)

But it looks like deploying an angular app to github pages is now more effortless with https://github.com/angular-buch/angular-cli-ghpages

Usage:

```
ng build --prod --base-href "https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY/"
angular-cli-ghpages [OPTIONS]
```

there is also a shorter ngh command available

```
ng build --prod --base-href "https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY/"
ngh [OPTIONS]
```